# Get id from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this simple string:

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="1" class="child">test</div>
</div>
```

How can I extract the id number (1) from this string?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `this HTML string`?

Comment: I mean this is a text string that is like HTML

Comment: Then the answer you received so far is invalid. Please post the code you're working with, so we can help more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With JQuery you can

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var str = $('<div id="parent"><div id="1" class="child">test</div></div>');
  console.log(str.find(':nth-child(1)').attr('id'));
</script>
```

Where nth-child is the target you want to get the id

Comment: this seems the most elegant solution. Thanks :)

Comment: If there could be multiple .child nodes, this may be better perf than running a find() against a pseudo-selector (note this is zero based, unlike nth-child): str.children().eq(0)

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = '<div id="parent"> <div id="1" class="child">test</div> </div>';

var d = new DOMParser().parseFromString( s, "text/xml" );

var id = d.firstChild.childNodes[1].attributes['id']; 

console.log( id );
```

Comment: I'm getting these errors: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (index):22
3
[object Attr]
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlString = '<div id="parent"><div id="1" class="child">test</div></div>';
var number = /id="(\d)"/.exec(htmlString)[1];

console.log(number); //outputs the number
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do a match on the string object that the HTML is stored in. so, if the string is called htmlString, then you would do something akin to

```
var id = htmlString.match(/id=\"([0-9]+)\"/)
```

That SHOULD net you the result, but if you deal with any data that is more complex than the example you've been given, you would need a different regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 let num = document.getElementById('1')
 let ans = parseInt(num.id)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unsure as to what you are trying to accomplish, one way  of getting of doing this is s to gather all like tagnames ("div" in this case) into an array and select the array index you desire (1 in this case) then reference the id - as follows:

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName("div")
alert(list[1].id);
```

Comment: Sorry if that's not clear. This is a text string not actual HTML